# jQuery 'vote' button affecting all elements

Tags: jquery

I have some divs that are being shown on my page via a foreach loop(php). In each div, there is a vote button, which when clicked is supposed to increment by 1. when I click the vote button in one div however, all the votes increase by 1. Here's my jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function($) {
     $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        success: function( data ) {
        $('.fa-plus').each( function(){
            $(this).on('click', function(){
                var counter = 0;
                counter = counter+1;
                $('.votes').html(counter);

            })
        });
        }                  
    })
```

And a snippet of my markup, which i trimmed for brevity:

```
foreach ($applications as $application){
    echo '<div class="widget-main">',
            '<span class="pull-right votes" id="votes-count"><strong>0</strong>  </span>',
            '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading remove-margin"><i class="fa fa-  heart fa-fw"></i>'.$votes.' Votes</h4>',                           
            '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading remove-margin"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Vote for '.$application ->_name.'</h4>',                        
        '</div>';
    }
```

P.S. I intend to insert the votes in a database.

Comment: You may find more help if you provide your markup too.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.fa-plus').on('click', function(){
 var voteup = $(this);
 $.ajax({
  url: "index.php",
  data: {"increasevote":1},
  success: function(response){
   voteup.closest('.votes').text(response)
   }
  })
})
```

- since you have multiple votes, in your data, include an identifier so your script know which row to update
- your php script gets the data passed, updates the db and returns the total votes
- return the total votes in the closest parent with class "votes"

Comment: Does this mean that in my php, i will be inserting "increasevote" into the database?

Comment: You may use your php script to update the relevant row[column] by 1.
Then return the updated value as your response.
So you update and select.
- you could use transactions, stored procedure to merge the 2 sql queries into a unit.

Answer (score 0):

$('.votes').html(counter); this line seems to be culprit. It assigns all the counter to all div with class **votes**.

You need to find parent div of vote button. I am not sure with your html however you can try this.

```
$(this).closest('.votes').html(counter);
```

Comment: when i use this nothing is changed in all the divs.

Comment: Hmm... Try the updated one. Now I know form your updated html, your .votes class is with span not div.

Comment: I tried using:   $('#votes-count').parent().html(counter); but for some reason when i do this, some elements are shifting to the bottom, lol! i have no idea why?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try this one. $(this).closest('.votes').html(counter);